# VB.net Read certain value from notepad file

Tags: vb.net

I'm just wondering how to read a certain value from a notepad file using vb.net.

My notepad would look something like this:

```
Name=Something
Status=Open
```

What I want is for VB.net to be able to read the value of either Name or Status. So I want a label to say "Something" if I wanted to get the value of Name.

Thanks

Comment: Show what you've tried so far.

Comment: @AndrewMortimer I'm afraid I havent tried too much at all, because I have no idea where to start. I've tried to search for answers but I've failed to find anything that will help me.

Comment: This is the `SteamReader` class that can help you reading files: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamreader(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-2

Answer (score 1):

This should get you started:

```
Dim FileName = "File full path"
Dim values = New Dictionary(Of String, String)()
Dim text = File.ReadAllLines(FileName)
For Each line In text
    Dim keyValuePair = line.Split("="C)
    values.Add(keyValuePair(0), keyValuePair(1))
Next
```

Please note:

1. There is no validations here on the location or the content of the file.
2. Code was written in c# and converted to vb.Net using an online tool.
   I've tested it in c# but not in vb.Net.

Comment: Tested it in VB.net for you, does the job, though you don't really need the brackets at the end of `Dim values = New Dictionary(Of String, String)()`

Comment: @Cal-cium thanks! It's been a long time since I last used vb.net, moved to c# some years ago and never looked back...

Answer (score 0):

... And if you want specific value use this:

```
Public Function getd(ByVal str As String, ByVal filepath As String) As String
    Dim tb As New TextBox
    tb.Text = My.Computer.FileSystem.ReadAllText(filepath)
    For Each l In tb.Lines
        If l.StartsWith(str & "=") Then
            Return l.Replace(str & "=", "")
        End If
    Next
End Function
```

Ex. `MsgBox(getd("Name", "C:\Users\user\Desktop\test.txt"))`